# Get border arround my triangles with 0.2vw width

Tags: html, css

I am trying in vain to get a frame with the thickness 0.2vw around the triangles.

I hope someone can help me, or tell me how to put a second clip-path with a different color and scaling over it, or have an better way for this.

The code is just a stripped down variant of my table, which is why I can't add a shadow in the parent  definition.

This is what I want, but a little more precise :D

[image]

```css
th{
  vertical-align: middle;
  padding-top: 0.5vw;
  padding-bottom: 0.5vw;
  text-align: left;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

tr{
  vertical-align: middle;
  padding-top: 0.5vw;
  padding-bottom: 0.5vw;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  height:30px
}

.routeTable td{
  border: 0.2vw solid black;
  font-size: 1.4vw;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.rect{
  -webkit-clip-path: polygon(50% 0%, 0% 100%, 100% 100%);
  clip-path: polygon(0% 0%, 0% 100%, 100% 50%);
  background-color: #357987;
  width: 2vw;
  height: 2vh;
}

table{ 
  width: 20% !important;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  vertical-align: middle;
  border-spacing:0;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  background-color: white;
}
```

```html
<table class="routeTable" style="margin-top: 1vw;">
        <tbody>
        <tr><td rowspan="2" style="color:black; font-size: 2vw;"             class="rect" class="left"></td><td rowspan="2"></td></tr>
        <tr></tr>
        <tr><td rowspan="2" style="color:black; font-size: 2vw;" class="rect"               class="left"></td><td rowspan="2"></td></tr>
        <tr></tr>
        <tr><td rowspan="2" style="color:black; font-size: 2vw;" class="rect"               class="left"></td><td rowspan="2"></td></tr>
        <tr></tr>
        <tr><td rowspan="2" style="color:black; font-size: 2vw;" class="rect"               class="left"></td><td rowspan="2"></td></tr>
        <tr></tr>                                                                       
        <tr><td rowspan="2" style="color:black; font-size: 2vw;" class="rect"></td><td rowspan="2"></td></tr>
        <tr></tr>                         
      </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: BTW You should use class instead of id - an id is supposed to be a unique identifier for a single element - having multiple elements with the same id is incorrect.

Comment: Oh ok, thank you for that information.